# one table with 2 fields referencing to the same table

Tags: foreign-keys

I have a table (GAMES)  containing 11 fields total (including the ID, primary key).
2 fields of this table reference (via foreign keys) to the same external table (TEAMS table), these are the HOME_TEAM and AWAY_TEAM fields

The table TEAMS contains all the teams, including their name, address, logo, etc.

My problem is as follows:

As i reference to the same table for 2 fields in the GAMES table how can i display these correctly. When I mean display i mean that i want to display the name of the team (stowed in the table TEAMS), and not the foreign key which is stowed in the table GAMES.
I get to display the foerign keys correctly, but how can i display the name of the team instead?

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

This is what i have now:

```
mysql_select_db($database_check_mag, $check_mag);
$query_getPosts = "SELECT games.id_game, games.seizoen, games.date, games.type, games.hometeam, games.awayteam, teams.id_team, teams.naam_team, teams.logo, teams.adres FROM games INNER JOIN teams ORDER BY games.date DESC";
$query_limit_getPosts = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getPosts, $startRow_getPosts, $maxRows_getPosts);
$getPosts = mysql_query($query_limit_getPosts, $check_mag) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPosts);
```

And this is how i display it:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<th scope="col" align="left">Date</th>
<th scope="col" align="left">Type</th>
<th scope="col" align="left">Game</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td align="left"><?php echo $row_getPosts['date']; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $row_getPosts['type']; ?></td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $row_getPosts['hometeam']; ?> - <?php echo $row_getPosts['awayteam']; ?></td>
<td><a href="games_edit.php?id_game=<?php echo $row_getPosts['id_game']; ?>">EDIT</a></td>
<td><a href="games_delete.php?id_game=<?php echo $row_getPosts['id_game']; ?>">DELETE</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_getPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPosts)); ?>
</table>
```

So now the echo $row_getPosts['hometeam'] and echo $row_getPosts['awayteam'] are displaying the id_team fields correctly but i want them do display the naam_team fields, which are different of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join the teams table twice 
once for each team 
like this:

> select g.id_game, homet.naam_team, awayt.naam_team   from games g,
>   teams homet, teams awayt   where g.hometeam = homet.id_team  and
>   g.awayteam = awayt.id_team;

Comment: i don't fully understand how you did it, here is the code, which then does not work as now it shows nothing anymore...
'SELECT games.id_game, games.seizoen, games.date, games.type, games.hometeam, games.awayteam FROM games INNER JOIN teams ON games.awayteam = teams.id_team AND games.hometeam = teams.id_team ORDER BY games.date DESC'

Comment: you are only joining the teams table once, so of course it doesnt work

Comment: run this:  select g.id_game, g.seizoen, g.date, g.type, g.hometeam, g.awayteam, homet.naam_team ht_name, awayt.naam_team at_name 
 from games g, teams homet, teams awayt 
 where g.hometeam = homet.id_team and g.awayteam = awayt.id_team
 ORDER BY g.date DESC;

Comment: Hi Yael, Thank you very much! This worked. Sorry for not being so good at this. Have a nice day. Dick

Comment: sure. if u need to do this often i recommend finding a good sql tutorial. also, if you dont mind, mark the answer as helpful so other ppl wont keep seeing it in the unanswered section